# How to export multiple CSVs from a single table in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So I have a table with many columns. I want to create a number of CSVs using an Azure Pipeline to get the data out of SQL. I want to split the data by City, District and Month. I.e. One CSV would contain all the data that corresponded to New York, Queens, January. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use Copy activity with a SQL source based on a query, so you can pick and choose the columns/rows you want to copy to the CSV sink. If you want to output multiple files, run multiple Copy activities.

Comment: Hi Joel, thank you. So this is a good solution however, when you have say 30 or 40 combinations of cities/districts this can get quite cumbersome. Is there a way to loop through every combination of city/district/month that exists within the table and export a CSV for each one?

Comment: You should be able to do it in Data Flow by creating SINK partitions based on the column values. Sorry I don't have time right now to put together a sample.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using the `Lookup` activity and copy activity included in the `Foreach` loop.

I tried to repro the scenario and was able to copy SQL data to multiple CSV files based on filter conditions.

**SQL Source:**

[image]

**Step1:**

- Create a **Source** data source for SQL connection.
- Using the `Lookup` activity, get the distinct values of State, city,
  Month from the SQL query.

[image]

**Output of Lookup activity:**

[image]

**Step2:**

- Connect the output of lookup activity to `Foreach` loop.
- Add the **value** of lookup output to the Foreach loop items.

[image]

**Step3:**

- Add `copy data` activity inside the Foreach loop.
- In Source, add **query dynamically** to filter the data based on the lookup output values.

  ```
   @concat('select * from [dbo].test_tb1 where state = ''', item().state, '''', ' and city = ''', item().city, '''', ' and Month = ''', item().Month, '''')
  ```

[image]

**Step4:**

- Create **CSV data source** for the Sink  (Optional - parameterize the output filename).

[image]

- Add the output filename dynamically.

  ```
  @concat(item().state, '_', item().city, '_', item().Month, '.csv')
  ```

[image]

**Step5:**

When you run the pipeline, the Foreach activity runs the number of times the value of the lookup activity and creates the CSV file for each loop.

[image]

**CSV Output:**

[image]